# UIImage CGImage: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: iphone, uiimage

Following is a snippet of my code:

in the .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *photo;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData *photoData;
```

in the .m file:

```
@synthesize photo;
@synthesize photoData;
...
photo = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]; {*}
...

NSLog(@"b1");
self.photoData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.photo);
NSLog(@"b2");
```

Here are the logs that I see in the console:

```
b1
*** -[UIImage CGImage]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x583b1d0
```

How can i prevent this "message sent to deallocated instance" problem? I am very new to this, so I'd really appreciate some background into why this is happening? (A pointer to some docs would be great too)

Thanks

UPDATE:
* The error occurs here. Thanks to codelark for pointing that out. If this line gets changed to the following, the error will not happen.

```
photo = [[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] retain];
```

Comment: the UIImage has been released somewhere in the code you clipped out. The problem lies there, and not in the extraction of the photo data.

Comment: Can you post some code showing how you're initialising your `photo` property?

Comment: codelark - u were dead on. Updating question with a line that I had earlier in my code.

Comment: echelon - i think u may have been referring to the same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

0x583b1d0 is likely the address of object in question (the value of self). You can use NSLog or printf with %p to print it.

**PK**